# Disable automatic header file renaming in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-luna

Is there a way to disable this feature in Eclipse CDT Luna?

https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn85#Header_File_Rename

I do not want my #include statements being replaced with relative paths as that is against my companies code style.

Example:
Before moving a header file:

```
#include <File.h>
```

After:

```
#include "../dir1/File.h"
```

Is there some setting which will disable this refactoring?

Answer (score 0):

The header/include management is controlled through a set of options in the Preferences: *C/C++* -> *Code Style* -> *Organize Includes*:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem as the original question. The settings you showed in your answer was my first idea as well. I disabled all settings under Organize includes, and set "Unused Includes and Forward Declarations" to "Keep". But Eclipse STILL occasionally renames my includes to something like "../../../common/foo/foo.h". It's pretty infuriating to be honest.

Comment: @Martin sounds like you have run into a bug then. Please submit a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT)